# $S$ be $\pi$-system on a set, given two measures on $\sigma(S)$, is there a topology on $\sigma(S)$ making $S$ dense, and the two measures continuous?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, continuity

Let $\Omega$ be a non-empty set , $S \subseteq \mathcal P(\Omega)$ be a Pi system (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_system ) on $\Omega$ , let $\sigma(S)$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $S$ (i.e. the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $S$ ) , and let $\mu ,\lambda:\sigma(S) \to [0,\infty]$ be a measure , then does there exist a topology on $\sigma(S)$ with respect to which $S$ is dense in $\sigma(S)$ and $\mu , \lambda $ are  continuous ?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want a topology *on* a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @Aweygan : yes exactly , that I want ... though thanks to Eric ( see answer below ) I think my dream is far from being true :p

Comment: @EricWofsey : Is that so ? Thank you ; could you please give a proof in your answer editing ? Any link would also be helpful ...

Comment: You shouldn't put a space *before* punctuation. Only after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not true in general.  For instance, let $S$ be the set of all subsets of $\Omega$ with at most one element, and let $\mu$ and $\lambda$ be counting measure.  Then for any topology that makes $\mu$ continuous, $\mu^{-1}((1,\infty])=\sigma(S)\setminus S$ must be open.  So unless $S=\sigma(S)$ (which happens only if $\Omega$ has at most one element), $S$ will not be dense in $\sigma(S)$.

However, it is true of $S$ is an algebra and $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are finite.  In that case, write $f:\sigma(S)\to [0,\infty]^2$ for $f(A)=(\mu(A),\lambda(A))$ and give $\sigma(S)$ the coarsest topology such that $f$ is continuous.  To show $S$ is dense in $\sigma(S)$, it suffices to show $f(S)$ is dense in $f(\sigma(S))$.  That is, we want to show that for all $A\in \sigma(S)$, $f(A)$ is in the closure of $f(S)$.  This follows from the monotone class theorem: note that $f$ is continuous with respect to monotone unions and intersections (here is where we use the assumption that $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are finite), so the set of $A$ such that $f(A)\in\overline{f(S)}$ is a monotone class.

Comment: By counting measure , do you mean cardinality measure ? okay .. I see ... $S$ must also be closed as well as dense ... hmm

Comment: Yes, $\lambda(A)=\mu(A)=|A|$.

Comment: why is it enough to show that $f(S)$ is dense in $f(\sigma(S))$ ? If you are using some general property of topological space only , then I am afraid this is not true , for example , take $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ as $f(x)=\sin x$ , then $f(\mathbb Z)$ is dense in $[-1,1]=f(\mathbb R)$ but $\mathbb Z$ is not dense in $\mathbb R$ ...

Comment: By definition of the topology on $\sigma(S)$, a set in $\sigma(S)$ is open iff it is the inverse image under $f$ of an open set.